# Android virtual device browser not working properly with Android 13

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I'm having this problem with Android Studio AVD, as you can see in the next pictures, when I open any web, it displays with strange errors.

I first realized this then opening a web view from an app, but then I tried opening any website on Chrome and it has the same error.

Wikipedia: [image: Wikipedia]  Amazon: [image: Amazon]

It only happens with Android 13, already tried with 11 and 9 and found no issues.
I recently upgraded my CPU to an AMD Ryzen 7 7700X 8-Core, but I don't know if there is any relation.
Any hints?